# Alias table group and order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used this sort of query structure before but for some reason this one is beating me.

So I have a table called users where all users tie back to KeyID. Some users have created passwords - some haven't. I want to show per Manager if there is a user who has created a password. I don't want to list all users per manager - just if there is any user who has created a password.

What am I missing that is so obvious?

```
CREATE TABLE test_output (
`UserID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`KeyID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Password` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`),
KEY `KeyID` (`KeyID`)
);

INSERT INTO test_output (KeyID,`Password`) VALUES
(1,NULL),
(1,'hello'),
(2,NULL),
(2,'hello2');
(3,NULL);

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `test_output`
    ORDER BY `Password` DESC
) testout
GROUP BY KeyID;
```

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: I have updated the question :)

Comment: Better show your expected output based on some sample input. I think it's still clumsy that what your expected output would be.

Comment: could you update the question with some sample data and also show us an example of the result that you expect?

Comment: I have now given a full working example.

Comment: Which is your Manager id on which you want grouping?

Comment: That is removed from the simple example - it now includes all rows I will just limit that in the full example.

Comment: I think now you want just the user which password is created.

Comment: Are you looking for all users who've set a password? Because this seems to be pretty easy to do without using subqueries or joins.

Comment: No I want a row per KeyID and whether they have / have not set a password.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the users with passwords, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM `test_output` t
WHERE Password IS NOT NULL;
```

If you want the list of users with passwords per manager:

```
SELECT KeyId, GROUP_CONCAT(UserId) as UsersWithPasswords
FROM `test_output` t
WHERE Password IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY KeyId;
```

If you want a count of users with passwords per manager:

```
SELECT KeyId, MAX(Password IS NOT NULL) as NumUsersWithPasswords
FROM `test_output` t
GROUP BY KeyId;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I need to see each KeyID and if the user has a password show that else show nothing (the empty password).

Answer (score 0):

This was what I was after ...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(KeyID) AS ki, tou.*
    FROM test_output tou
    ORDER BY `Password` DESC
) u2

GROUP BY u2.KeyID
```

It was the select distinct on the alias table was what fixed it.

Comment: What is `select distinct(keyid) as ki, tou.*` supposed to do?  `distinct` is not a function in any database that I'm aware of.